# Vertically merge dataframe on a specific column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, lookup

I have two datasets

```
df1=pd.DataFrame([[1,'CAN_US','MCS'],[1,'ITL_US','MCS'],[1,'MEX_US','MCS'],[1,'KER_US','MCS']], columns=['ID', 'Group_N','Domain'])

df2=pd.DataFrame([['BCS','JPN_US'],['MCS','MKL_US'],['MCS','GAA_US']], columns=[ 'Domain','User_Group'])

df1

ID   Group_N   Domain
1    CAN_US    MCS
1    ITL_US    MCS
1    MEX_US    MCS
1    KER_US    MCS

df2
Domain   User_Group
BCS      JPN_US
MCS      MKL_US
MCS      GAA_US
```

Where I want to do lookup & merge these two dataframe verically where there is a match for Domain, such that the output should be

```
ID   Group_N   Domain
1    CAN_US    MCS
1    ITL_US    MCS
1    MEX_US    MCS
1    KER_US    MCS
1    MKL_US    MCS
1    GAA_US    MCS
```

I have tried with `res_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], join='outer', axis=0)`
& `res_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="Domain", how="inner")` but didnt got the expected output.

Comment: I really don't care about accepting my answer but the one provided by *@gtomer* does not give your expected output (*see* https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMD2h.png). So, I'm a bit confused :p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove domains which do not appear in df1:

```
domains = df1['Domain'].unique()
df2 = df2[df2['Domain'].isin(domains)]
```

Rename the column:

```
df2.rename(columns = {'User_Group': 'Group_N'}, inplace=True)

res_df = pd.concat([df1, df2],  axis=0)
```

No need for join.

This is the output:

```
   ID Group_N Domain
0   1  CAN_US    MCS
1   1  ITL_US    MCS
2   1  MEX_US    MCS
3   1  KER_US    MCS
1   1  MKL_US    MCS
2   1  GAA_US    MCS
```

Comment: for `res_df['ID'] = 1` the value `1` cannot be static, it could be some other value, so for different domain & groups it could vary

Comment: Also your code give all the values occurring for df2, wherein I want only those values that matches Domain in both dataframe, pls refer the expected Output

Comment: See updated code above. Regarding ID - what is the expected logic?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution with [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
d = df1.set_index("Domain")["ID"].to_dict()
​
out = (
    pd.concat([df1, df2.rename(columns={"User_Group": "Group_N"})])
        .loc[lambda x: x["Domain"].isin(df1["Domain"])]
        .assign(ID= lambda x: x["Domain"].map(d))
)
```

Or this one with [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)/[`lreshape`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.lreshape.html) :

```
out = (
    pd.lreshape(df1.merge(df2), {"Group_N": ["Group_N", "User_Group"]})
        .drop_duplicates()[df1.columns]
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   ID Group_N Domain
0   1  CAN_US    MCS
1   1  ITL_US    MCS
2   1  MEX_US    MCS
3   1  KER_US    MCS
1   1  MKL_US    MCS
2   1  GAA_US    MCS
```